# Database migration For Aws lambda,Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, database-migration, claudiajs

Can anyone give me a really good example of using clauida with sequelize & doing db migration from AWS lambda to the database hosted in AWS RDS server.